# Projectile motion in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, game-physics

I'm basically trying to make a basketball game where the user can decide the **direction** of the ball and the intensity of the **force** applied to it.

I haven't done the basket yet because I got stuck trying to do the **projectile motion**.

The main idea is to decide the force by pressing the letter "*r*" in the keyboard and then with "*w*" start a rotation of a vector who will give the direction for the parabolic motion of the ball.

But the motion of the ball is not working. I'm sorry that I couldn't provide the image of the ball that I used but every image can work.

I tried to follow a **code** that I found **online** but still the ball is **not following** the direction of the **vector** and is not following a correct **parabolic** **motion**.

This is my full code:

```
import pygame
import math

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen_x = 900
screen_y = 500
ball_x = 40
ball_y = 40
time = 0
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_x, screen_y))
pygame.display.set_caption("Basketball Game")

jumping = False
X_POSITION = 400
Y_POSITION = 375
Y_GRAVITY = 1
JUMP_HEIGHT = 20
Y_VELOCITY = JUMP_HEIGHT

VEL_BALL = 15
ARROW_X = 500
ARROW_Y = 300
LENGHT_FORCE = 49

ANGLE = 0

ball = pygame.image.load("ball.svg.png")
ball = pygame.transform.scale(ball, (80, 80))
ball_rect = ball.get_rect(center = (X_POSITION, Y_POSITION))
ball_width = ball.get_width()

def ball_path():
    Vx = math.cos(angle)* JUMP_HEIGHT
    Vy = math.sin(angle)* JUMP_HEIGHT
    distx = Vx * time
    disty = (Vy * time) +((-4.9 * (time)**2)/2)
    
    newx = round(distx + X_POSITION)
    newy = round(Y_POSITION-disty)

    return(newx, newy)

    #X_POSITION = newx
    #Y_POSITION = newy

def find_angle(pos):

    sX = X_POSITION
    sY = Y_POSITION
    try:
        angle = math.pi / 2
    except:
        angle = math.pi / 2
    if pos[1] < sY and pos[0] > sX:
        angle = abs(angle)
    elif pos[1] < sY and pos[0] < sX:
        angle = math.pi - angle
    elif pos[1] > sY and pos[0] < sX:
        angle = math.pi + abs(angle)
    elif pos[1] > sY and pos[0] > sX:
        angle = (math.pi * 2) - angle

    return angle


run = True
while run:
    VECTOR_STARTPOINT = pygame.math.Vector2(X_POSITION, Y_POSITION)
    VECTOR_ENDPOINT = pygame.math.Vector2(100, 100)
    CURRENT_ENDPOINT = VECTOR_STARTPOINT + VECTOR_ENDPOINT.rotate(ANGLE)

    screen.fill(BLACK)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False


    keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        jumping = True
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_d] and X_POSITION < screen_x-ball_width//2:
        X_POSITION += VEL_BALL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_a] and X_POSITION > 0 + ball_width//2:
        X_POSITION -= VEL_BALL

    screen.fill(BLACK)
    
    #draw force line, red below, white above
    FORCE_MAX = pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 0, 0) , (400, 50), (50, 50), 5)
    FORCE = pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE , (LENGHT_FORCE, 50), (50, 50), 5)


    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_r] and LENGHT_FORCE <= 400:
        LENGHT_FORCE += 5

        #coould do it with no hard coding
        if LENGHT_FORCE <= 200 and LENGHT_FORCE > 99:
            print("low")
            JUMP_HEIGHT = 20
            Y_VELOCITY = JUMP_HEIGHT

        if LENGHT_FORCE > 200 and LENGHT_FORCE < 300:
            print("medium")
            JUMP_HEIGHT = 25
            Y_VELOCITY = JUMP_HEIGHT

        if LENGHT_FORCE >= 300 and LENGHT_FORCE < 400:
            print("strong")
            JUMP_HEIGHT = 30
            Y_VELOCITY = JUMP_HEIGHT

        if LENGHT_FORCE == 399:
            print("maximum")
            JUMP_HEIGHT = 35
            Y_VELOCITY = JUMP_HEIGHT

    #start moving vector
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_w]:
        ANGLE = (ANGLE + 5) % 360
        VECTOR_LINE = pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, VECTOR_STARTPOINT, CURRENT_ENDPOINT, 4)
    
    #stop moving vector
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP :
        if event.key == pygame.K_w :
            if Y_POSITION < screen_y and Y_POSITION >= 0:
                pos = CURRENT_ENDPOINT[0], CURRENT_ENDPOINT[1]
                angle = find_angle(pos)

                VECTOR_LINE = pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 0, 0), VECTOR_STARTPOINT, CURRENT_ENDPOINT, 4)
                
                time += 0.05
                po = ball_path()
                X_POSITION = po[0]
                Y_POSITION = po[1]
                
            else:
                time = 0
                Y_POSITION = 375


    if jumping:
        Y_POSITION -= Y_VELOCITY
        Y_VELOCITY -= Y_GRAVITY
        if Y_VELOCITY < -JUMP_HEIGHT:
            jumping = False
            Y_VELOCITY = JUMP_HEIGHT
        ball_rect = ball.get_rect(center = (X_POSITION, Y_POSITION))
        screen.blit(ball, ball_rect)
    else:
        ball_rect = ball.get_rect(center = (X_POSITION, Y_POSITION))
        screen.blit(ball, ball_rect)


    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have an angle of say 45 degrees you can convert it to radians

```
radians = (degrees * math.PI)/180
```

once you have radians you can get the x and y components using sin/cos

```
x1 = x0 + math.cos(radians)*speed
y1 = y0 + math.sin(radians)*speed
```

where x0,y0 are your origin point and x1,y1 is the next point ...

if you wanted to go the other way ie you have x0,y0 and x1,y1 and you need to find the angle that is even easier just use `math.atan2(y1-y0, x1-x0)`

i honestly have no idea if this answers your question ... but I noticed a lack of these formula in your code

Comment: I tried to add this formula right away but it didn't solve my issue. I think I made a mistake somewhere else, but thank you for your answer!